# i Want to ETL some Data from a db2 v5 server Using Informatica on a VM to another server that has sql server 2017

Tags: networking, ibm-midrange, informatica-powercenter, db2-luw, ibm-information-server

see i can Picture this as 3 VMs running altogether  but ... i don't know how to connect them so that i can define my Connections to the source and target, as they are not on the same network...

so we have DB2 v5 running on OS/400    > windows VM with informatica power center >  sql server 2017 on windows vm

how can i Connect to those VMs while they are not on the same network and how also to define those remote connections in Informatica Power center designer and work flow Manager ???

thank you

Comment: Does the VM running SQL Server have access to VM running DB2i?  If so, you can create a Linked Server in SQL Server to retrieve the data directly from DB2i.

Answer (score 0):

Question doesn't have much details. Here are my thoughts -

1. Connect to DB hosted in VM1 from VM2 - You can connect to any Database using Datadirect ODBC. You need to mention IPs in host file.
2. Informatica configured in VM1 and you want to access it from VM2, make sure you set things up in host file so your VM1 can talk to VM2. Its just TCP/IP connection.